# Prepared SELECT statement in .Net

Tags: c#, mysql, select, prepared-statement

I can't understand what I am doing wrong, I can't seem to SELECT with a prepared statement. However I can INSERT with a prepared statement.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM code_post WHERE name = ?postRequired LIMIT 1",  dbcon);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?postRequired", requestString));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.fill(ds, "result");
try {
             thisBlog = ds.Tables["result"].Rows[0];
} catch {
             invalid();
             return;
}
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with the matter, but according to the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html) it looks like variables in the prepared statements should be prefixed with `@`, not `?`.

Comment: I read that you had to use @ for prepared statements, and not ? because it caused compatibility issues. I'm not sure now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fill a DataSet you will need a DataAdapter.

Try this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM code_post WHERE name = ?postRequired LIMIT 1",  dbcon);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?postRequired", requestString));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter dAdap = new MySqlDataAdapter();
dAdap.SelectCommand = cmd;
dAdap.Fill(ds, "result");
try {
             thisBlog = ds.Tables["result"].Rows[0];
} catch {
             invalid();
             return;
}
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thanks very much. Is there the need to do the try/catch ? Can I check rows of the td table with an if/else instead maybe?

Comment: Use of try catch...depends.. However given your code you can always do a check of ds.Tables["result"].Rows.Count > 0

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

`DataAdapter` represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are used to fill the `DataSet` and update a SQL Server database.

The `SqlDataAdapter` provides this bridge by mapping [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill.aspx), which changes the data in the DataSet to match the data in the data source

Check the following syntax:

```
private static DataSet SelectRows(DataSet dataset,
    string connectionString,string queryString) 
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = 
        new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```